# Visual Studio Web Site Project (not Web Application) support

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, vs-web-site-project

I just realized that I can't see the website project template in Visual Studio 2010 (Visual C# > Web).

I would like to see websites die (for many reasons, mainly not having a .proj for msbuild). Did this in-fact happen? Has VS 2010-2012 dropped support for websites? Is there an official announcement somewhere confirming (I looked)?

---

Shame on any project using web site template. On a side note, have you seen any "products" come out of the box as a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually website is not project. When you go to File -> New, you can choose between project and website. It's the same in VS 2010 and 2012.

And actually I think that website is ideal for small and simple site.

Comment: *Brain fart* Ya, that is right. I disagree though. Websites should never be an option. Why would websites benefit small websites?

Comment: Dynamical compilation at least.

Comment: Web sites were introduced starting with VS 2005, web application was absent at first and then they added it with SP, because many developers were not satisfied with web sites. Now they just keep option of web site just as legacy from VS 2005.
Of course, professional web site should be created as web application.

Comment: why do you want dynamic compilation? Maybe single file deployment (which are bad)? You can publish a .aspx and .cs from a web application and IIS will still do dynamic compiling. Dynamic compilation is a IIS feature, not a Web Site feature.

Comment: What do you mean under single file deployment? 
About dynamic compilation: you can edit source file directly at the server, without republishing it. Actually in one of my previous project, it was client's request.

Comment: Single file deployment: Deploying just one .aspx/.ascx with confidence that nothing else is touched. Web applications have all .aspx/.ascx codebehinds in a single .dll so it isn't possible to only deploy changes for "X" and not "Y". But, you can still deploy single files with web application with slight changes to the codebhind and .aspx (and not deploying the .designer.cs). Great for emergencies and you will get dynamic compilation and editing on the server. There is no reason to use a website and they should be removed from visual studio.